# Get Timezone diff between server and client? PHP Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

Scenario:

Servers systems are all over the world.
Web page on the client machine is requesting data.

Issue:

How to know the time zone offset between any server and any client machine?

Code:

```
var DocumentTime = new Date();
function GetTimeZoneOffset()
    {
        var nTime = DocumentTime.getTime();
        var sUrl = xxxPhpUrl + '?TimeZoneOffSet=' + nTime;
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET", sUrl, true);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
            {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4)
                {}
            }
            xhr.timeout = 30000;
            xhr.ontimeout = TimeOut;
            xhr.send(null);
        }
        nNow = null;
        nTime = null;
        sUrl = null;
    }

<body  önload="GetTimeZoneOffset()"
```

PHP

```
if (isset($_GET['TimeZoneOffSet']))
{
    $ClientTime = $_GET['TimeZoneOffSet'];
    $ServerTime = time();
    $ServerTime = $ServerTime*1000;
    $Diff = $ServerTime - $ClientTime;
    echo $Diff;
    echo " Server ";
    echo $ServerTime;
    echo " and client ";
    echo $ClientTime;
}
```

Webpage Posts a timestamp to the php on the server (using get date function) and php should take the timestamp and give difference between the webpage timestamp and its local timestamp.

Output:
The difference is hardly 70000 microseconds. even though the server timezone is in PST and client is in EST. Is this correct?

How do i achieve this?

Comment: Why do you care about the server's time zone at all? On the server, use UTC. The server's location should almost certainly be irrelevant. You may well want to know the client's current UTC offset... that's easy enough to get; getting the client's time zone is harder (but is discussed in other questions).

Comment: Our server is having two hours of data that we have to display on a trend. But however the data read is off by 3 hours or x hours depending on the server timezone. So if the timezone offset between server and client is known (if i could get the diff or the localtime of the server), i can shift the data by that many minutes on the trend.

Comment: You know the offset between the server and GMT, right? And you know the offset between the client and GMT?  So, you also know the offset between the server and client.

Comment: The timezone offset in Client (javascript) is "getTimezoneOffset()" and i was able to get this. How to get the timezone offset on server side (php). I am having hardtime using php timezone_offset_get manual to get the offset.

Comment: @developerwjk you said "You know the offset between the server and GMT, right?", no i do not know the offset between my server and the GMT. Can you tell me how can i get the offset between the server and GMT?

Comment: @amarasat, I meant, you know where the server is. You already said "the server timezone is in PST." Whether you know how to get it programmatically or not, you know it.

Comment: Oh i am sorry, i was just giving an example. The server is everywhere, it could be anywhere. Please take a look at this code and see if i am doing it correct. Here am i getting the offset between the current server and the GMT?
 
$ServerTimeZone = date_default_timezone_get();
$ServerDateTimeZone = new DateTimeZone($ServerTimeZone);
$Offset = new DateTime('now', $ServerDateTimeZone);

echo $Offset->getOffset();